# Emulate/Simulate iOS in Linux

Tags: linux, ios, ubuntu-10.04

I'm developing a web app that apparently is having problems in iOS devices. The problem is that I don't own an iOS device and I develop in Linux Ubuntu. I'm looking for a way to emulate/simulate this OS in Linux (especially the browser), but haven't found anything.

So far, what I've found is the iOS SDK's Simulator, but that is meant for the Mac. And also some emulator for Windows. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: The *web* app is intended mostly for regular browsers. However, a few users try to see it using an iPhone, and I needed to verify some problems they were having.

Comment: If it's a layout issue I recommend installing the Konqueror web browser. Then look in settings to be sure it uses Webkit layout engine (same as safari).

Comment: Here is an article wich should solve your problem - http://www.proreactnative.com/How-to-Develop-iOS-Apps-on-Linux-Using-React-Native/

Comment: [macOS VM with QEMU+kvm](https://github.com/kholia/OSX-KVM/), actively maintained

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The only solution I can think of is to install VMWare or any other VT then install OSX on a VM.

It works pretty good for testing.

Comment: Doing this, as no other option seems available (except for actually acquiring the mobile devices in question).

Comment: is it possible to deploy for tests an app on iphone using Linux?

Comment: With this solution, yes.

Comment: Is there a legal way to do this?  I stupidly bought an OSX CD thinking that I could install it in VirtualBox, but it turned out to be much more compilcated than that.  I think you need some kind of hardware image which is not strictly legal to obtain.  No?

Comment: Virtualisation of some of the mac os is often not permited. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20965/does-apples-license-for-os-x-allow-it-to-be-virtualized-on-an-hp-pc

Comment: I have a "hackintosh" in VirtualBox (plenty of instructions online). Apart from the licensing issues, the performance is pretty bad and graphics glitches are common. Unless you only need a CLI environment, IMHO **this option is not suitable for serious development**.

Comment: As far as I know, legally you can only install Apple OS on Apple hardware. To circumvent this issue, I've been using https://www.lambdatest.com. The downside is that you will have to deploy your web app publicly for being able to access it thorough here.

Answer (score 43):

On linux you can check epiphany-browser, resizes the windows you'll get same bugs as in ios. Both browsers uses [*Webkit*](https://webkit.org/).

Ubuntu/Mint:

`sudo apt install epiphany-browser`

Comment: This isn't a catch-all solution. The engine may be the same, but I have encountered some ios browsers which error on pages that render fine on epiphany. YMMV

Comment: Working well for me to fixing layout bugs on cordova hybrid app

Comment: This may not be a perfect solution but it definitely helped me solve my javascript issue that was happening in Safari on iPhone without having access to one.

Comment: @Besworks That's it. When I've answered this, I got into this question because I was developing something in Cordova. As I remember, I've used this to solve some layout bugs. So it may be an amend about this answer.

Comment: Thanks to epiphany I could solve some iOS bugs. Thanks so much for sharing this!

Comment: This is underrated answer. Got the same bugs as on real iOS

Comment: good idea for some (but not all) sorts of bugs, Epiphany is now officially known as "Gnome Web" browser, https://apps.gnome.org/en-GB/app/org.gnome.Epiphany/

Comment: This is quite a quick and free solution to test most IOS bugs.. it helped me many times.. good answer..

Comment: This used to work but as of today there are too many differences.

Answer (score 11):

[BrowserStack.com](http://www.browserstack.com/)
On this site, you can emulate a lot of iOS's devices online.

Comment: Isn't this site testing, and not actual iOS application testing?

Comment: its only for remote testing purpose ...not for actual simulator on laptop

Answer (score 5):

1. Run [Ripple emulator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc)(retired as of 2015-12-06) on Chrome
2. Run [iPadian](http://www.ipadian.net/) on WineHQ
3. Run [QMole](https://github.com/chriskmanx/qmole) on Linux or Android
4. Run XCode on [PureDarwin](http://www.puredarwin.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, this approach is better, https://saucelabs.com/mobile, mobile testing in the cloud with selenium

Comment: Link not working.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [screenfly](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/). It worked great for me.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Thanks!

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina, there is nothing else to add to my suggestion. Not a long answer required. Cheers

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina Yours is neither an answer nor a comment

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, there is no such a thing as iOS emulator on windows or linux, there are only some gameengines that enable you to compile same code for both iOS and windows or linux and there is a toolchain to compile iOS application using linux. none of them are realy emulator/simulator things. and to use that toolchain you need a jailbreaked iOS device to test binary file created using toolchain. I mean linux itself can't run the binary created itself. and by the way even in mac simulator is just an intermediate program which runs mac-compiled binary, since if you change compiling for iOS from simulator or the other way, all the files are rebuild. and also there are some real differences, like iOS is a case-sensitive operation while simulator is not.

so the best solution is to buy an iOS device yourself.