# Developing iOS app using apache cordova in windows 8

Tags: ios, windows, cordova

The majority of tutorials I saw online were showing apache cordova iOS app development on OS X needing XCode and stuff. Is it possible to build an app in Apache Cordova and then compile it for different target platforms ? That should be the whole concept, right ? I'm just confused about developing iOS app on Windows machine with Cordova.

Comment: Check out the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23682404/65775). The question was about developing on Ubuntu but the solution is the same.

Comment: thanks I found that helpful :)