# Ionic Capacitor iOS on linux

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

Considering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2406839/7784165) answer, it is not possible to run Xcode on Arch Linux.
Capacitor iOS [documentation](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/ios/) says that I need it to run iOS emulation.
 Is there a way to emulate iOS device on Manjaro using Ionic Capacitor?

Comment: Seems like it's not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311289/emulate-simulate-ios-in-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible, iOS requires Xcode and macOS

Answer (score 2):

you can run xcode on linux NATIVELY using [darling](https://www.darlinghq.org/)

> Darling is a translation layer that lets you run macOS software on Linux

once [installed](https://docs.darlinghq.org/build-instructions.html) you can install `xcode`

via command-line developer tool following this [link](https://docs.darlinghq.org/installing-software.html#command-line-developer-tools)